# Copy Div Content to Textarea or text with the same font-family style

Tags: javascript, html

I have certain code which copies `<div>` content to `<textarea>`, but then it doesnt copy the style (font family) of the `<div>`. It paste in the normal font. How do i fix this problem?

*HTML*

```
<input type="text" id="styledText" placeholder="Place your Name..." size="50" name="styledText" class="changeMe">
<div id="fontselect" class="changeMe" onClick="copyText()" style="font-family: Times New Roman;font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold; cursor:pointer;">Place your Name...</div>
```

*Javascript*

```
function copyText() {
    var output = document.getElementById("fontselect").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("styledText").value = output;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bearing in mind the `font-family` will apply to *all* of the inserted text, so any individually styled words/content will lose their differentiation:

```
function copyText() {
    var output = document.getElementById("fontselect"),
        textElem = document.getElementById("styledText");
    textElem.value = output.value;
    textElem.style.fontFamily = window.getComputedStyle(output,null).fontFamily || output.style.fontFamily || output.currentStyle.getCurrentProperty('font-family');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#fontselect, #styledText {
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```